# STM32L010RB How to read ADC multichannels

Tags: c, stm32, adc, hal

Please help advice.
I am fighting several days with option ADC.

I am using 2 channels ADC IN0 and IN1 on STM32L010RB microcontroler via HAL library.

If checking apart then everything are good but when I am checking together it I have all time the same problem: first channel rewrite data on second channel and I have the same data on IN0 and IN1 in terminal

Function for select IN0.

```
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> //Library for work with string

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
char Tx_Data[31] = {0};
volatile uint32_t Axis[2] = {0};

ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC_Init(void);

void ADC_Select_CH0(void)
{
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig_0 = {0};
      /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
      */
    sConfig_0.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
    sConfig_0.Rank = 0;
      if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig_0) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
}

void ADC_Select_CH1(void)
{
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig_1 = {0};
      /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
      */
    sConfig_1.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
    sConfig_1.Rank = 1;
      if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig_1) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
}

void ADC_Check_CH0(void)
{
      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc); // start ADC
      HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc, 100);
      Axis[0] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
      HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc);
}

void ADC_Check_CH1(void)
{
      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc); // start ADC
      HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc, 100);
      Axis[1] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);
      HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc);
}
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_ADC_Init();
  HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED); // simple channel
  while(1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      ADC_Select_CH0();
       ADC_Check_CH0();

      ADC_Select_CH1();
       ADC_Check_CH1();

      sprintf(Tx_Data, "Axis X: %d;\nAxis Y: %d;\r\n\n\n", (int)Axis[0], (int)Axis[1]);
                   HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)Tx_Data, strlen(Tx_Data), 1000);
  }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLLMUL_8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLDIV = RCC_PLLDIV_2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART2;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart2ClockSelection = RCC_USART2CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_ADC_Init(void)
{
  hadc.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc.Init.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_79CYCLES_5;
  hadc.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DIRECTION_FORWARD;
  hadc.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerFrequencyMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoPowerOff = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();


  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Green_LED_GPIO_Port, Green_LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);


  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SW_Button_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(SW_Button_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);


  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Green_LED_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(Green_LED_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

void Error_Handler(void)
{

  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
 
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{

}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGPU7.png)

Comment: What is the output when you use hadc_ch0 and hadc_ch1 instead of hadc?

Comment: Apart? from 0 to 4095, depending on variable resistance. I use 10k from arduino Joystick

Comment: Provide the definition of hadc. Also Tx_data is a string type, you are converting it to uint8_t*. What's the exact output on the terminal?

Comment: of course I did it, sorry that does not added all code. I have changed my post and added full code

Comment: Try using HAL_Delay ( 10 ) after ADC_Check_CH0(); and  ADC_Check_CH1(); also refer to https://deviot.vn/tutorials/stm32f1.23165131/adc-voi-stm32.73721443. Make sure that the EOC bit is cleared as shown in the timing diagram from the web link.

Comment: How to check EOC bit via HAL library? Need to use interrupt?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202938/stm32-adc-conversion-using-hal